# Confusing facing of a-text inside a-sky primitive

Tags: 3d, three.js, aframe

I don't understand behaviour of a-text primitive in aframe 0.8.0.

I have two simple cases:

1. a-text directly inside scene - works as expected ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gxgjqjau/))

   `<a-scene>
       <a-text value="some text" color="#000000" position="0 2 -1"></a-text>
   </a-scene>`
2. a-text inside a-sky - text looks like it's rotated 180 degrees around y-axis, and backface is visible ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wwrm2zcn/2/))

   `<a-scene>
       <a-sky radius="10">
           <a-text value="some text" color="#000000" position="0 2 -1"></a-text>
       </a-sky>
   </a-scene>`

Is it expected behaviour? Why it works like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like this, because `a-sky` is just a `a-sphere` with its `scale` equal to `scale: '-1 1 1'` which flips it around. Along with other child entities :)

It's done on purpose to map the sphere's texture on the interior surface

---

Check out the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/scale.html#reflection), it's quite described there.